# Interval handling after application goes into Background State in react-native

Tags: react-native

In one of my application screens i have  a timer (interval). Sometimes when i click the home button the AndroidOS decides to kill my app, once i start it again i can see the interval wasn't clear as i see stuff jumping to my screen. I tried to use the AppState to catch when the app goes into background state so i could clear the interval, but this solution is not good for me because sometimes the AndroidOS doesn't kill the app and once i resume it i want to get the interval running. Any ideas?

p.s componentWillUnmount does not occur when OS kills the app.

Comment: How much time are you using on interval?

Comment: every second interval, why?

Comment: Because a short setInterval can freeze the app.

Comment: no it's not the case sorry